# Better derivation for the gravitational potential energy

Tags: newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy, integration, singularities

I was shown this derivation for the gravitational potential energy, and I'm not very happy about it assuming that $\frac{1}{\infty} = 0$. Is there a better derivation, either using a completely different method, or one similar that avoids $\frac{1}{\infty}$?

\begin{align}
\text{work done} &= \int F dx\\
&= \int_{\infty}^{r} F \, dr\\
\text{substitute} \,F &= \frac{G M m}{r^2}\\
\text{work done} &= \int_{\infty}^{r} \left(\frac{G M m}{r^2}\right)\,dr\\
&= G M m \int_{\infty}^{r} \frac{dr}{r^2}\\
&= G M m \int_{\infty}^{r} r^{-2} \, dr\\
&= G M m \left[\frac{r^{-1}}{-1}\right]_{\infty}^r\\
&= - G M m \left[\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{\infty}\right]\\
\text{Assuming} \, \frac{1}{\infty} = 0\\
\text{gravitational potential energy} &= -\frac{G M m}{r}
\end{align}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're just having an issue with [improper integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral). All you need to do is use limits, since you can prove that $\lim_{r\to\infty}1/r$ goes to $0$.

\begin{align}
W &= \int F dx\\
&= \lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{b}^{r} F \, dr'\\
&=\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{b}^{r} \left(\frac{G M m}{r'^2}\right)\,dr'\\
&= G M m\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{b}^{r} \frac{dr'}{r'^2}\\
&= G M m\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{b}^{r} r'^{-2} \, dr'\\
&= G M m\lim_{b\to\infty}\left[\frac{r'^{-1}}{-1}\right]_{b}^r\\
&= - G M m\lim_{b\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{b}\right]\\
&= -\frac{G M m}{r}+0\\
U &= -\frac{G M m}{r}
\end{align}

Alternatively, if you just hate using $\infty$ altogether, we can be "more physical" by replacing $\infty$ with a distance that is "much larger" than $r$. Indeed, you can do the integration to get to

\begin{align}
U &= -\frac{G M m}{r}+\frac{G M m}{b}\\
&=-\frac{G M m(r-b)}{rb}
\end{align}

and then assume that $b\gg r$ so that

$$\frac{r-b}{rb}\to-\frac{1}{r}$$